# Unique Index on Array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Say we have a collection of documents similar to this:

```
{
  foo: "Bar",
  foos: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I would like to define a unique index such that no document identical to this one can be inserted into the database.

```
db.stuffs.ensureIndex({ foos: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

Seems to block any document containing a `foos` array with any intersection, eg. if the document above was already in the database, then

```
{
    foo: "Bar",
    foos: [ 1 ]
}
```

Would also be blocked.

```
> db.stuffs.ensureIndex({ foos: 1 }, { unique: true })
> db.stuffs.insert({ foo: "Bar", foos: [ 1, 2, 3 ]})
> db.stuffs.insert({ foo: "Bar", foos: [ 1 ]})
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.stuffs.$foos_1  dup key: { : 1.0 }
```

I would like to be able to make insertions of [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 1, 3 ], etc. but not two [ 1, 2 ]

Comment: This is a little to abstract to explain the use case here. Generally though contain the array in a single document with `$addToSet` or live with separate documents and no array. You would be better off explaining your real use case for any kind of helpful answer. Indexes won't do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

The array index will not meet your requirement. But I think you can switch to the other format to store your data.

If there is no need to use the feature of array (such as $addToSet, $push op), you can simply hash/map your data to another format. e.g.: [1,2,3] to the string "1,2,3".

While I assume that you want to remain the array operations in order to make some updates. Then you can try the subdocument below:

```
db.stuffs.ensureIndex({ foos: 1 }, { unique: true })  // build the index for the sub doc
db.stuffs.insert({ foo: "Bar", foos: {k:[ 1, 2, 3 ]}})
db.stuffs.insert({ foo: "Bar", foos: {k:[ 1 ]}})
db.stuffs.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("54081f544ea4d4e96bffd9ad")}, {$push:{"foos.k": 2}})
db.stuffs.insert({ foo: "Bar", foos: {k:[1, 2]}})
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.stuffs.$foos_1  dup key: { : { k: [ 1.0, 2.0 ] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this question. Explains why Unique Index won't work in this case.

[Unique index in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044677/unique-index-in-mongodb)

> To index a field that holds an array value, MongoDB creates an index
>   key for each element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If the array that you want to index is of constant size, you can create a unique multikey index like this:

```
collection.createIndex({"coordinate.0": 1, "coordinate.1": 1}, {unique: true})
```

`coordinate` is an array of size 2.

When I try to insert a duplicate coordinate, it returns an error as expected.